# ngrx 9 doesn't give me data

Tags: angular, ngrx

I started learning ngrx yesterday. So, for some practice I decided to rewrite my component using it. It used to work nice without ngrx.
My showcase.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-showcase',
  templateUrl: './showcase.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./showcase.component.css']
})
export class ShowcaseComponent implements OnInit {
  books$ = this._store.pipe(select(selectShowcaseList));
  constructor(private _store: Store<IAppState>) {    
  }    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._store.dispatch(getBooks());
  }
}
```

showcase.effects.ts (I guess trouble is here):

```
@Injectable()
export class ShowcaseEffects {
    getBooks$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('[Showcase] getBooks'),
        mergeMap(() => this.booksService.getBooks()
          .pipe(
            map(books => ({ type: '[Showcase API] BooksLoaded Success', payload: books })),
            catchError(() => EMPTY)
          ))
        )
      );


    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private booksService: BookService,
        private _store: Store<IAppState>
    ) { }
}
```

showcase.reducer.ts:

```
export const showcaseReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(showcaseActions.getBooksSuccess, (state, {books}) => ({ ...state, books: books})),
)
```

showcase.actions.ts:

```
export const getBooks = createAction(
    '[Showcase] getBooks'
)

export const getBooksSuccess = createAction(
    '[Showcase API] BooksLoaded Success',
    props<{books: Observable<Book[]>}>()
);
```

showcase.state.ts:

```
export interface IShowCaseState {
    books: Observable<Book[]>;
}

export const initialState: IShowCaseState = {
    books: null
}
```

showcase.selectors.ts:

```
export const selectShowcase = (state: IAppState) => state.showcase;

export const selectShowcaseList = createSelector(
    selectShowcase,
    (state: IShowCaseState) => state.books
);
```

my states are:

```
export interface IAppState {
    showcase: IShowCaseState;
    test: ITestState;
}

export interface IShowCaseState {
    books: Book[];
}

export const initialState: IShowCaseState = {
    books: null
}
```

app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AuthenticationComponent,
    ShowcaseComponent,
    CartComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    CreateBookComponent,
    TestComponent //ttt
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    //запихнуть в отдельный модуль
    StoreModule.forRoot({ books: fromShowcase.showcaseReducer, test: fromTest.testReducer }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([ShowcaseEffects]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 10
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Console tells me that variable books$ is undefined.
I haven't found nice example with the new NGRX 9.X syntaxes for my purposes. If you have any NGRX 9.X app examples where effects with data fetching services are used send me a link please.

Comment: is your reducer set up correctly? what does the books state look like

Comment: @shahidfoy yes. I've made some less complex components without effects with the same practices for reducers and that's works fine. What do mean by book state? It doesn't has it's own state yet because I can't even even get all the books and move on.

Comment: Is this in a lazy loaded module? I had problem with similar consequences and the solution was delaying the usage of the store a little bit. Apparently that slice of the store wasn't ready to be used yet. I've even opened an [issue on ngrx repo](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2394), but as I couldn't reproduce the behavior, I've closed it.

Comment: @julianobrasil no, I'm using app.module too keep it simple while I'm just learning.

Comment: Modify your question by posting the parts of your `AppModule` where you start your store, effects etc. Also, you have a very peculiar structure... you're saving an observable to the books attribute in the store. How does your selector work (`selectShowcaseList`)? Post it here. It's not common to have an observable in  the store.

Comment: Oh, forget my last comment. I've misread your code above.

Comment: What do you get on redux dev tools?

Comment: @julianobrasil after [Showcase API] BooksLoaded Success in Actions I see payload which is array of Books[] from the server (that works fine), but State says that books are empty object.

Comment: I hope this can help with the ngrx 8+ syntax https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/ngrx-creator-functions-101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the wrong data on the payload. Your reducer is expecting an object with a `books` attribute, but instead, it's getting an array of books. You can fix it by changing a little bit your effect:

```js
import * as fromActions from '...showcase.actions'

...

getBooks$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(fromActions.getBooks),

  // instead of returning an empty operator in catchError, let's return an empty array
  switchMap(() => this.booksService.getBooks().pipe(catchError(() => of([])))),

  // the main problem in your code was this "payload: books"; use, instead, "payload: {books}"
  map(books => fromActions.getBooksSuccess({books})),
));
```

And let's fix your `getBoosSuccess` action

```js
export const getBooksSuccess = createAction(
    '[Showcase API] BooksLoaded Success',
    props<{books: Book[]}>()
);
```

Also, fix your state:

```js
export interface IShowCaseState {
    books: Book[];
}

export const initialState: IShowCaseState = {
    books: []
}
```

I've put something together [on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma611976466433166).

Comment: Thank you. But now I have the next issue: console says that books in showcase.selectors.ts is undefined (updated my question with that file), but NgRx Store DevTools shows the right state with all of the books.

Comment: Initialize books with an empty array. Why do you define IShowCaseState twice?

Comment: There are parts of your code that I don't have access to, so I've built this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma611976466433166). It'll be easier if you compare, by yourself, your code and mine.

Comment: Error was in app.module. I had to write `StoreModule.forRoot({ showcase: fromShowcase.showcaseReducer, test: fromTest.testReducer })` instead of `StoreModule.forRoot({ books: fromShowcase.showcaseReducer, test: fromTest.testReducer })` Thank you so much for your help!